# buffer from points using dismo R

Tags: r, buffer

I am trying to create a buffer around several points using the function circles in the R package dismo. The problem arises with points that are close to the 180 or -180 longitude. In these cases the buffer is not a circle but a band that connect both sides of the map extension. Probably I am missing some basic option, but I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this issue. Below an example code and its result.

```
library(dismo)
library(dismo)
xx<-cbind(c(-175.20, -106.65,-103.97,-17.76),c(-21.13,35.08,36.78,28.65))
pp<-as.data.frame(rep(1,4))
zz<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(xx,pp)
cc<-circles(zz,1000000,lonlat=TRUE)
plot(cc)
```

[image: result from code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is because the circle is split across the +180 line. You can fix this by reprojecting to the same lat-long coordinates but using the `lon_wrap` option:

```
> plot(polygons(cc),lwd=2)
> axis(1)
> plot(spTransform(polygons(cc),"+init=epsg:4326 +lon_wrap=180"),lwd=2)
> axis(1)
```

[image]

This won't work if you have circles covering all longitudes, because then one is going to get split at some point. You might also have to reproject your background data.